# PHP - Laravel 5.4 view data

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get data from mongodb.

my db structure as follows
[image: database]

when I try to display user ids with following code segment, it works fine.

```
<body>
    <ul>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <li>{{$user->_id}}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</body>
```

[image: working code]

but when I try to get user first-name with following code, it gives an error.

> Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'

```
<body>
    <ul>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <li>{{$user->first-name}}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</body>
```

[image: error code]

Why this happens? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyphened Column Names is not a good practice you should use Underscore.

For Now You can use this.

```
$user->getAttribute('first-name');
```

Comment: one of my colleague made the database with mongodb. Main project is made with clojure. So no problem with that. I'm setting up a admin panel to the same system with laravel.  Now I'm stucked with the database.
Your answer works fine mate. Saved my day.